# How to implement Xamarin.Forms custom RadioButton renderer? (repost)

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-renderer

*Note: I originally posted this a couple days ago, but it got closed due to insufficient/unclear detail. Hopefully this repost passes muster*

I'm creating an Android/iOS app using Xamarin.Forms.
I've found that selected RadioButtons render in red on Android:
[image]
I want to use a different color that's in my app's theme.

I found a Xamarin forum post which described the standard mechanism for this, which is to implement a custom renderer by adding the following code *in the Android project*:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.RadioButton), typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class MyRenderer : RadioButtonRenderer
    {
        public MyRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control != null)
            {
                Control.ButtonTintList = ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've added the code (renderer is in my Android project); it compiles, runs (on Android), the button appears & functions, etc.
However, neither MyRenderer() nor OnElementChanged() is ever called.

Is there something additional needed to cause the app to use the custom renderer?

Thanks!

Comment: To change the control colors on android, add this to `styles.xml`, as a child to `resources`: `<item name="colorControlActivated">[yourColor]</item>` and `<item name="colorAccent">[yourColor]</item>`, where `[yourColor]` is a hex color code. This will set the colors of radio buttons, switches and checkboxes for android.
The real problem is fixing this on iOS too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that it seems Custom Renderers only work on *custom classes*.
So, in order for this to work you **MUST** define your own custom class and *attach the renderer to your class*. I was referencing Xamarin.Forms.RadioButton when I should have been referencing my type.

Does **not** work:

```
ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.RadioButton), ...
```

**Does** work:

```
ExportRenderer(typeof(MyApp.MyRadio), ...
```

So the minimal working implementation is to create your custom class in your main project (neither Android or iOS specific):

```
namespace MyApp
{
   // All that's needed is the simplest derived class ever:
   public class MyRadio : RadioButton
   {
   }
}
```

then in your Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyApp.MyRadio), typeof(MyApp.Droid.MyRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
   ... same as the code in the question above
}
```